# Unable to see dynamically created DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to create a DataTable with a list of user names and password text boxes for the corresponding users using checkboxes.
The code goes like this:

```
    private void createAndBindSchemaUsersDataGrid()
    {
        schemaUserDataGrid = new DataGridView();

        this.schemaUsers.Controls.Add(this.schemaUserDataGrid);


        DataTable usersTable = new DataTable();
        usersTable.Columns.Add("User Name", typeof(string));
        usersTable.Columns.Add("Change Password", typeof(CheckBox));
        usersTable.Columns.Add("Password", typeof(TextBox));
        usersTable.Columns.Add("Confirm Password", typeof(TextBox));            

        //Loop through the list of fetched users
        for (int i = 0; i < usersList.Count; i++)
        {
            usersTable.Rows.Add(usersList[i], false, "", "");

        }
        //binding dataTable to DataGrid
        schemaUserDataGrid.DataSource = new BindingSource(usersTable, null);
        schemaUserDataGrid.Visible = true;
        schemaUserDataGrid.Refresh();
        schemaUserDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        schemaUsers.Refresh();

        schemaUserDataGrid.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(schemaUserDataGrid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChange);
        schemaUserDataGrid.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(schemaUserDataGrid_CellValueChanged);


    }
```

But when this code is run, I see nothing but an empty dgv on the tab page.
What's going wrong here?

Comment: You should have textboxes, checkboxes and other controls on UI (i.e. in DataGridView). DataTable should contain only data (i.e. name and password strings in your case)

Comment: Ok, so far I added userNameCol and checkbox directly as DataGridViewColumn(with ReadOnly set to true) and DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn respectively. How do I associate the password textBoxes with this datagridview? Can I do it without a DataTable?

Comment: Passwords are both DataGridViewTextBoxColumns

Comment: It works! I confused DataGridViewTextBoxColumns with DataGridTextBoxColumn. My bad. Thanks!

Comment: Good :) Thus problem is solved, you can close question

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to not use DataTable for adding checkboxes, textboxes etc to a DataGridView.
One should use DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn and DataGridViewTextBoxColumns instead and add them as columns to DataGridView.